# SweetAlert confirmar eliminar

Tags: sweetalert

Actualmente estoy trabajando este codigo de un ejemplo de tabla de busqueda, eliminacion y edicion de campos, quiero utilizar Sweetalert para hacer más vistosas las alertas de javascript y aunque he logrado que se visualicen en mi codigo javascript no logro que elimine el campo, ahora si utilizo la función confirmDel elimina sin ningun problea.

¿De que manera debe quedar el codigo javascript para que el sweet alert elimine?

```html
var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.10.1/sweetalert2.all.min.js";
 script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.4.2/sweet-alert.min.js";
 script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.10.1/sweetalert2.all.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(script);
    //for CSS file
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/0.4.2/sweet-alert.css" />');



function lista_libros(valor){
 $.ajax({
  url:'../Controllers/libros.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'valor='+valor+'&boton=buscar'
 }).done(function(resp){
  //alert(resp);
  var valores = eval(resp);
  html="<table class='rwd-table'><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>ID Solicitud</th><th>Usuario</th><th>Miniauditorio</th><th>Equipo</th><th>Fecha-Solicitud</th><th>Fecha-Evento</th><th>Evento-Culmina</th><th>Hora-Inicio-Evento</th><th>Hora-Fin-Evento</th><th>Detalles</th><th>Estatus</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
  for(i=0;i<valores.length;i++){
   datos=valores[i][0]+"*"+valores[i][0]+"*"+valores[i][2]+"*"+valores[i][3]+"*"+valores[i][4]+"*"+valores[i][5]+"*"+valores[i][6]+"*"+valores[i][7]+"*"+valores[i][8]+"*"+valores[i][9]+"*"+valores[i][10]+"*"+valores[i][11];
   html+="<tr><td>"+(i+1)+"</td><td>"+valores[i][0]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][1]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][2]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][4]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][5]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][6]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][7]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][8]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][9]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][10]+"</td><td>"+valores[i][11]+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modallibros' onclick='mostrar("+'"'+datos+'"'+");'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></button><button class='btn btn-danger' onclick='sweetDelete("+'"'+valores[i][0]+'"'+")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
  }
  html+="</tbody></table>"
  $("#lista").html(html);
 });
}
function guardar(){
 var datosform=$("#formLibro").serialize();
 $.ajax({
  url:'../Controllers/libros.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:datosform+"&boton=actualizar"
 }).done(function(resp){
  if(resp==='exito'){
   $('#exito').show();
   lista_libros('');
  }
  else{
   alert(resp);
  }
  
 });
 
}
function mostrar(datos){
 //alert(datos);
 var d=datos.split("*");
 //alert(d.length);
 $("#idusuario").val(d[0]);
 $("#miniauditorio").val(d[2]);
 $("#equipo").val(d[4]);
 $("#fechaevento").val(d[6]);
 $("#eventoculmina").val(d[7]);
 $("#horainicio").val(d[8]);
 $("#horafin").val(d[9]);
 $("#status").val(d[11]);
 $("#detalles").val(d[10]);
 

 
}

function eliminar(id){
 //alert(id);
 $.ajax({
  url:'../Controllers/libros.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'idusuario='+id+'&boton=eliminar'
 }).done(function(resp){
  alert(resp);
  lista_libros('');
 });
 
}
//



//
/*
function confirmDel(id)
{
  var agree=confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminarlo? Los datos se eliminarán permanentemente");
  if (agree==true){
     eliminar(id);
  }else{ 
   return false;
  }
}
*/
function eliminar(id){
  $.ajax({
  url:'../Controllers/libros.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'idusuario='+id+'&boton=eliminar'
 }).done(function(resp){
  alert(resp);
  lista_libros('');
 });
}

/*sweet alert*/
function sweetDelete(id){
swal({
  title: '¿Estás Seguro?',
  text: 'No podrás recuperar esta información!',
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminalo!',
  cancelButtonText:  'Cancelar!',
  closeOnConfirm: false
},
function(){
  swal(
    'Deleted!',
    'Your file has been deleted.',
    'success'
  );
});
}
/* Tratado de realizar una confirmacion para eliminar, hace la pregunta pero al confirmar no elimina
function confirmDel()
{
  var agree=confirm("¿Realmente desea eliminarlo? ");
  if (agree) function eliminar("+'"'+valores[i][0]+'"'+");
  return false;
}

*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás usando las versiones recientes de SweetAlert, deberías utilizar la sintaxis de promesas, y simplemente agregas el llamado al código que elimina o a la función eliminar en `then()`:

```
function sweetDelete(id){
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
  confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
  cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
  buttonsStyling: false
}).then(function () {
  // código que elimina
  $.ajax({
    url:'../Controllers/libros.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:'idusuario='+id+'&boton=eliminar'
   }).done(function(resp){
    lista_libros('');
   });
  swal(
    'Deleted!',
    'Your file has been deleted.',
    'success'
  )
}, function (dismiss) {
  // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
  // 'close', and 'timer'
  if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
    swal(
      'Cancelled',
      'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
      'error'
    )
  }
}

)
}
```

Comment: El código corrió hermoso, solo tuve que eliminar este alert: alert(resp); Ya que me estaba generando una segunda ventana de alerta.

Muchas gracias.